# Elastic Beanstalk - Delete environment failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I created an environment and through it a database.

I went to RDS and renamed the instance name and then delete the RDS instance

Now I am trying to delete the environment and the procedure fails:

> ERROR Stack deletion failed: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [AWSEBRDSDatabase].

What can I do in order to detach the environment from the RDS?

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andreas What you can do is rename the RDS instance back to the original one and takes a Snapshot of it.
`if you don't rename and try to delete the beanstalk what happens is beanstalk will keep on looking for the RDS Instance.`

Now you can delete the Beanstalk, after successful deletion of the environment you can again create the RDS Instance via that Snapshot (which you have created previously)

What else you can try is go to the Configuration tab of the beanstalk and change the configuration of Database and update the beanstalk. This will preserve your beanstalk env also and changes the RDS configuration also.

Comment: Dear @Karan,
Thank you very much for your reply but
the RDS does not exist anymore...

Comment: In Configuration tab - Modify database, I can see only the endpoint which points in the non-existed rds
I do not see how can I change it...

Comment: Actually I created a new RDS instance with name the missing one and then the environment termination completed
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

For me helped to going to Cloud Formation and deleting stack there

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-deleted-rds-database/